# Scroll no topo de uma DIV

Tags: javascript, rolamento

```css
#map{
    background-color: black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:300px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: scroll; /* adicionado para permitir a rolagem */
    position: relative;
    direction: rtl;
}
.icon{
    position: absolute;
    top: -10%;
    left: 0%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="map"> 
  <!--Elementos-->
     <div class="icon">
        <div class="content-ocorrencia">
           Teste
        </div>
     </div>
</section>
```

Como fazer um scroll de uma div alcançar os elementos que fogem das extremidades do topo de uma div, Isto é, um elemento  tem um top: -20%; como fazer para que o scroll vertical da div venha a reconhecer e permitir o rolamento até o elemento que fugiu do topo de uma div cujo valor de top é -20%?
No código abaixo certamente quando executado vão aparecer uma tela preta somente, dado isto, a objetivo deste problema é achar de alguma forma uma solução para que o elemento HTML com a classe icon consiga ser interpretado pelo rolamento do #map.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: o código foi adicionado

Comment: Remova o `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`. teste novamente o código e depois reformule sua pergunta.

Answer (score -4):

Assim, é pouco código pra analisar, da pra ver que pelo css você tem mais elementos que somente o esses ai, o código dessa div inteira seria melhor pra analisar, mas enfim, fui atrás de um código meu pra passar pra você pra ver se ajuda, e uma tabela que se passa do tamanha vertical vira scroll.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello, World!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body><div style="width: 100%; overflow: auto;">

                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <form method="post" class="smart-form" novalidate="novalidate">

                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="width:6%">
                                        <button name="cancelar" id="cancelar" value="sim" style="color:white;background-color:#a90329;width: 30px;height: 30px;border:0;border-radius: 5px;" class=""><span class="fa fa-trash-o" style="font-size: 18px;"></span></button>
                                        <button name="dar_baixa" id="dar_baixa" value="sim" style="background-color:#eb731c;width: 30px;height: 30px;border:0;border-radius: 5px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd" style="font-size: 15px;color:white"></span></button>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>N° Documento</th>
                                    <th>Guia</th>
                                    <th>Cálculo</th>
                                    <th>Competência</th>
                                    <th>Data de vencimento</th>
                                    <th>Entidade ou servidor</th>
                                    <th>Ação</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="tbody">
                              
                                    </tr>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td>2</td>
                                    <td>3</td>
                                    <td>4</td>
                                    <td>7</td>
                                    <td>8</td>
                                    <td>9</td>
                                    </tr>

                            </tbody>
                            <form>
                        </table>

                    </div>
  </body>
</html
```

Comment: Rodrigo, o overflow auto não é a solução, pois ele não reconhece elementos que ultrapassam os elementos que estão acima do escopo do container com valor negativo: top: -50px. Mais de qualquer forma obrigado por ajudar.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Quando postei não tinha visto todo o seu código, agora que vi aqui, só não entendi bem a ideia que você quer fazer, dei uma testada aqui e meio que o seu scroll funciona sim, só tem que ajustar a altura do elemento icon.

Answer (score -4):

Para um elemento container "reconhecer" os elementos internos que estão ultrapassando os limites da caixa e mostrar a barra de rolagem, o elemento filho precisa ocupar um espaço dentro deste container.

Quando você utiliza a propriedade `position`, o elemento em questão passa a não seguir o fluxo normal de posicionamento. Com o valor `absolute` em específico nesta propriedade, o elemento não irá mais ocupar um espaço dentro de seu container e a sua posição será relativa ao elemento raiz da página, sobrepondo qualquer outra caixa.

Em termos simples: ao usar `position: absolute` o elemento perde a sua relação de layout com o elemento pai.

Você pode ler mais sobre isto e entender o posicionamento dos elementos aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp ou aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

(Nestes links você provavelmente encontrará também uma alternativa correta para chegar ao resultado que espera).